# extract N from each group

Tags: bash, awk, sed, split

I have a csv file with two columns: 'id' and 'values'

An id can appear multiple times in the file with different values. I want to perform a stratified sampling of the data to obtain a smaller file, that contains exactly, or at most, N of each id.

Example input:

```
    a    1,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    a    2,4,3
    a    4,2,3
    a    4,4,4
    b    3,4,4
    b    8,8,8
    b    3,3,3
    c    4,5,6
    c    5,5,4
```

Desired output (N=2):

```
    a    1,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    b    3,4,4
    b    8,8,8
    c    4,5,6
    c    5,5,4
```

At this point I don't care which id's from a group are taken, but bonus points if it is random.

As the text file can be very large I prefer a memory efficient (linux) command line solution (i.e. bash, awk, sed, etc.)

Comment: please add what you tried to solve this... with `awk`, you can use an array with id as key and print if that key has been seen at most N times

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm not very familiar with awk. I created a solution using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Sundeep's suggestions I made a solution using shuf and awk with an array[id] count construction (for N=10):

```
shuf ./data.csv | awk '{count[$1]++} {if (count[$1] < 10)print $1, $2}' ./data.csv
```

This takes the first 10 items of each id.

Comment: for random, you can use something like `shuf data.csv | awk -v n='2' '++seen[$1]<=n' | sort`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one in awk, implementing some kind of randomness. It reads the file twice. On the first round it counts keys and on the second outputs records using <s>some</s> a kind of probability. Not extensively tested but it should avoid division by zeros and the 2 last records for each key are returned if the gods of probability haven't intervened before that:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM -v n=2 '  # n is the count of keys wanted
BEGIN {
    srand(seed)                 
}
NR==FNR {                       # on the first run
    nc[$1]=n                    # ncound for each key (2)
    c[$1]++                     # count of keys
    next
}
{
    if(nc[$1]>0 && c[$1]>0 && (nc[$1]/c[$1]/(1-rand()))>1) {
        print
        nc[$1]--                # reduce n count for key when printing
    }
    c[$1]--                     # keys left counter reduces at each iteration
}' file file
a    1,2,3
a    4,2,3
b    8,8,8
b    3,3,3
c    4,5,6
c    5,5,4
```

Another run produced:

```
a    2,2,3
a    4,2,3
b    3,4,4
b    8,8,8
c    4,5,6
c    5,5,4
```

`( nc[$1] / c[$1] / (1-rand()) ) > 1` This guarantees that the 2 (or `n`) last records for each key are returned if none were printed earlier, for example `nc=2; c=2` then `nc/c==1` and `1/[0-1[ > 1` always. `rand()` returns values in range `[0-1[` and to avoid `/0` there is `/(1-rand())` Random distribution may not be even, though.

Comment: Great answer and being able to make it reproducible using a seed is awesome. However, iterating the file twice makes it a bit less practical for my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -v n=2 '++arr_seen[$1] <=n'  file
    a    1,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    b    3,4,4
    b    8,8,8
    c    4,5,6
    c    5,5,4
```

**Input**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file
    a    1,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    a    2,4,3
    a    4,2,3
    a    4,4,4
    b    3,4,4
    b    8,8,8
    b    3,3,3
    c    4,5,6
    c    5,5,4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ n=2; awk -v n=$n 'arr[$1]<n{arr[$1]++;print $0}' file
    a    1,2,3
    a    2,2,3
    b    3,4,4
    b    8,8,8
    c    4,5,6
    c    5,5,4
```

Brief explanation,

- `n=2`: set the desired show-up times as a bash variable `n`
- `arr[$1]<n`: The id would be the key of the array, and the value for each id would be the value for each key. If the value of the key `<n`, print the line and then `arr[$1]++`.